How to shut down the Node server when we have a UNHANDLED REJECTION or UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
In Laravel if we get a unhandled exception or which were application cannot resolve it will show the error and shutdown the Laravel server completely from the app itself. So after fixing the error we can restart the server.
So, I'm trying to do the same in Node.js as well. But, here it is just showing the error message and still keep running the server.
I tried below codes to stop and print errors.
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log('UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION!  Shutting down...  ');
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
  process.exit(1);
});

Above server variable I get from the server listening instance. I created the server instance like below.
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
});

When I run above code I get the console error like this for (UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION) instead of shutting down the server:
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION!  Shutting down...  
ReferenceError: x is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dineshlakmal/PhpstormProjects/UdemyNode/Section 4/complete-node-bootcamp/4-natours/starter/server.js:35:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1546:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1691:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1317:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1127:12)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:315:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:217:24)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:166:5)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:30:49
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...


app already shut down, but nodemon is waiting for file change. so run it without nodemon (use node).   btw [nodemon] app crashed is already saying that it's stopped

I'm sorry If I asked a dumb question. I'm very new to node js. Thanks for the instant reply @jonrsharpe

Hello try this method:
 process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {

  console.log(err.name, err.message);
  server.close(() => {
    process.exit(1);
  });
});


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
